# Rubik's Cube's Group

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

Is there an article somewhere with an exhaustive study of the Rubik's Cube Group $G$? Such as computing some subgroups of it or exhibiting some elements of its center $Z(G)$? I tried googling it and searching in this page but I could not find any such article.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I attended a presentation by Davidson on the work that went into showing that "20 moves suffice" to solve the cube, given any starting position. It was quite impressive, and you can learn a bit about that [here](http://www.cube20.org/). Here's a [complete mailing list](http://www.cube20.org/cubelovers/biglist.html) from the ancient internet, if nothing else :)

Comment: This has been discussed on our site many times (hardly a surprise :-). For example [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/332252/11619) looks promising. Does that answer your question? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Just fyi, I'm fairly certain the center is of order 2. (But this becomes evident only after studying which permutations of a rubik's cube can occur, or specifically, their parity)

Comment: Yes the centre has order $2$ and its nontrivial element is flipping all $12$ edge faces.

Answer (score 1):

Adventures in Group Theory talks somewhat extensively about the Rubik's Cube.

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0801869471/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801869471)

Comment: oh I should add that it proves what the center of the group is (trivial move and "superflip")